# Executing curl command with process builder java

Tags: java, curl

I want to execute this curl command from a java application. I know I can use the Process Builder, but I dont know how to correctly format the command.

```
curl -X POST -d '{"user":"hello","command":"activate"}' "http://<examplewebaddress>"
```

This is what I have tried:

```
ProcessBuilder testCurlCommand = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-X", "POST", "-d", "user=hello", "-d", "command=activate", "http://exampleweaddress>"
```

I have also tried many different variations of that incorporating the curly brackets, but it doesn't like that. Everything else works but I am unsure of the formatting for the arguments

Comment: Maybe it is the correct format, maybe it isn't - try it!

Comment: So this i Java question or CURL syntax question? Is it question after all ?\

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
But it is also equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. 
Also include what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing.

Comment: I want to run this command in a java application using the process builder which the syntax will look something like: ProcessBuilder testCurlCommand = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-X", "POST", "-d","user=hello", "command=activate",  "http://<examplewebaddress>" but this doesnt work, I dont know how to format it with the brackets and such.

Comment: To clarify your question use [edit] option.

Comment: Does the `curl` command work without java?

Comment: Try with `new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-X", "POST", "-d", "'{\"user\":\"hello\",\"command\":\"activate\"}'", "\"http://<examplewebaddress>\"")` since `'{"user":"hello","command":"activate"}'` looks like single argument of command you want to run so it should be single string, not series of strings. Same about `"http://<examplewebaddress>"` (I escaped `"` with ``\`` but you may not actually need them - I don't know curl syntax to be sure)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to like the "'{ part of it. And yes the curl command does work without java.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to like"? Did you get compilation error, runtime exception, wrong results?

Comment: Netbeans was flagging it, and then when trying to run this error appears: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: <any>"

Comment: So it is compiler which doesn't like this code. Since it compiled fine for me I will assume that you didn't copy it but written it by hand. Or you copied incorrect part (notice that solution ends before "since" word).